# NDSolve ERROR: There are more dependent variables, than equations, so the system is underdetermined

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I have a question concerning NDSolve and a system of differential equations. I have 4  variables and 4 equations. Why do I get this ERROR :There are more dependent variables, {f[j,p],U[j,p],(f^(0,1))[j,p],(U^(0,1))[j,p]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined. ???

```
V = 1000; ρ = 0.000013; L = 37;

eqns = {V p D[f[j, p], j] +  j D[U[j, p], j] +  U[j, p] + 6  ρ L j == 0, 
    V f[j, p] + V p D[f[j, p], p] + j D[U[j, p], p] == 0};

vars = {f[j, p], U[j, p]};

inits = {f[5, 10] == 0.1048, U[5, 10] == 3.6};

res = NDSolve[{eqns, inits}, vars, {j, p}]
```

Comment: A little tough reading your work, however I believe your problem may arise from using "=="; this tests if the left and right hand side are equal, it is not used to assign values

Comment: This set of equations can be solved manually to yield, `0.002886` j^2/2 + j U[j, p] + 1000 p f[j, p] == c`, where `c` is a constant.  So, there are too few dependent variables.

Comment: Your initial conditions doesn't make any sense. What are the four variables and four equations?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my earlier comment, `eqns` can be rewritten as

```
eqns1 = {V D[p f[j, p], j] + D[j U[j, p], j] + 6 ρ L j == 0, 
    V D[p f[j, p], p] + D[j U[j, p], p] == 0};
```

That the two are equivalent can be verified by

```
Simplify[eqns == eqns1]
(* True *)
```

Introducing the new dependent variable,

```
g[j, p] == V p f[j, p] + j U[j, p]
```

further simplifies the equations to

```
eqns2 = {D[g[j, p], j] + 6 ρ L j == 0, D[g [j, p], p] == 0}
```

Neither `DSolve` nor `NDSolve` can handle these equations without human assistance, because there are two equations but only one dependent variable.  However, the solution of these two equation clearly is

```
(* g[j, p] + 3 ρ L j^2 == c *)
```

with `c` a constant to be determined by a boundary condition.  Inserting `inits` from the question yields after a small amount of algebra,

```
{* c -> 1066.036075 *}
```

Note that `g` is independent of `p`.